# RegularExpression validator: Should not allow single zero

Tags: c#, asp.net-3.5

How do I restrict single zero in a numeric textbox? Textbox can accept any number but it should not accept only zero as value.

Example: "1984500" is valid but "0" is invalid.

Edited:

Is it possible to give maximumvalue as infinity?

Comment: Instead of stating what is restricted, can you also indicate what is/are accepted? E.g. any integer except zero? Or any decimal above zero? Or..???

Comment: Morning? It's 7:14 PM for me ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use a [RangeValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.rangevalidator.aspx) and set the minimum value to 1.

```
<asp:RangeValidator ID="range1" RunAt="server"
                    ControlToValidate="Textbox1"
                    MinimumValue="1"
                    MaximumValue="2147483647"
                    Type="Integer"
                    EnableClientScript="false"
                    Text="The value must be greater than 0" />
```

Comment: Agreed; this is a better way than the RegEx because the RegEx will still allow an invalid number to be entered.

Comment: What bad number could be entered by that RegEx? Although personally I'd go with the range too.

Comment: Is it possible to give maximumvalue as infinity

Comment: @Yuriy: You can enter a number that is larger then the allowed value for an int (999999999999999999999999, say). Geetha: No.

Comment: @silky: int isn't in the question.

Comment: @Geetha -- if you don't specify a maximum value, then it simply doesn't do the maximum check.  Any number specified would still need to convert to whatever numeric data type you are using, however, so technically you can't specify infinity (I think this is true even if you use double as the type as there is no representation of infinity that will convert).

Comment: I have tried without using maximum value but it showing error.Maximum value canot be converted to the type integer

Comment: Interesting.  I could have sworn it wasn't required.  You could always set it to the maximum integer value: 2,147,483,647.

Answer (score 2):

Using a [RegularExpressionValidator](http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GGLS_enUS335US335&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=regularexpressionvalidator) with the following regex: `\d*[1-9]\d*`

Answer (score 0):

This should take care of it. Allows a single digit 1-9 or a collection of digits 2 or more.

```
[1-9]|\d{2,}
```

Comment: I'm not sure 00 should be allowed.